# Angular2 adding HTML Element to directive on touchevents

Tags: mobile, drag-and-drop, touch, angular, touch-event

I'm trying to do a drag&drop directive which works with HTML5 dragging and also with mobile `TouchEvents`.

On Angular2 I have the `dragstart` event on which I can set the `DragImage` which works fine for me. But I think I don't have the same thing for `TouchEvent touchstart` so I'm not sure how to implement it.

In my opinion the only solution I have is to add DOM Element dynamically to directive.

So if this is the only way to do it my question is, how can i copy the ELEMENT where i attached the directive and copy it into DOM, on the right of the originally?

```
constructor(private elemRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
```

I can inject `ElementRef` and `Renderer` where `elemRef.nativeElement` is my DOM. But how can I copy this and add it to my component or `Directive`?

Comment: No idea why someone voted to close. Looks like a proper question to me.